# Is it possible to destructure an irrefutable pattern on self in the parameter list?

Tags: methods, rust, destructuring

It seems that the name `self` used for the first parameter is what determines whether a function in an `impl` block is a method or an associated function. Does this mean that it is impossible to destructure an irrefutable pattern on `self` in the parameter list itself? I am aware that `self` can be destructured in the body.

Here is some code that explores the possibilities:

```rust
struct Foo(u8, u8, u8);

impl Foo {
    pub fn method     (&self            ) {} // Type not needed
    pub fn method_too ( self     : &Self) {} // Type allowed
    pub fn associated ( name     : &Self) {} // Name not self => not method
    pub fn destructure(Foo(_,_,_): &Self) {} // Destructure in parameter list
    pub fn long_winded(&self) { let Foo(_,_,_) = self; } // Destructure in body
}

fn call_them(f: Foo) {
    f.method     ();
    f.method_too ();
    f.associated (); // ERROR: not a method
    f.destructure(); // ERROR: not a method
    f.long_winded();

    Foo::method     (&f); // method call syntax not mandatory
    Foo::method_too (&f); // method call syntax not mandatory
    Foo::associated (&f);
    Foo::destructure(&f);
    Foo::long_winded(&f); // method call syntax not mandatory
}
```

Comment: Yes, to my knowledge. Because [the `self` parameter is part of the method's syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#methods), it's quite literally what separates methods from functions. It's possible that Rust could use @-patterns thus (e.g. `fn foo(&self@Foo(ref x))`, but I'm guessing nobody has ever cared enough to even propose it since the gain is limited to nonexistent.

Comment: Methods are also associated functions

Comment: @ramslök Reasonable enough nomenclature. In that case is there a name for an associated function that is *not* a method?

Comment: @jacg: They are sometimes called [_static methods_](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/methods.html), although there is nothing actually static about them, but in C++/C#/Java they use the keyword `static`, so...

Comment: @Masklinn Good enough for an answer IMO.